# Running QTP test without opening associated files

Tags: runtime-error, qtp

I am running a QTP test that has some libraries associated to it. When I run the action and an error is encountered in one of the libraries, the associated library file is opened and the error is displayed. Is there a way to NOT make the associated file open and be displayed in QTP in this case?

Reason: I have the libraries associated to a common server and is accessed from many PCs. So if any one of those PCs encounters an error, the associated library file is locked by that PC and cannot be modified in the main server.

Thanks,
Charan

Comment: I´d create local copies of the libraries to avoid this problem. You might encounter additional issues with the scenario you´re currently using as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable error handling, use

```
on error goto 0
```

this will disable the error handling and will move on 
also the best option would be to handle the error by yourself by using

```
on error resume next
```

hope this helps